# CRUD Laravel Update in database one to many relationship

Tags: laravel, crud

I have a CRUD app with cars and for every car I have fields to create a car and images to upload. Everithing is ok, I have one to many relationship and for a car I can have multiple images . When I create a car and I upload photos these photos are stored correctly in database and in my public/images director. The problem is when I want to make the UPDATE par, I don't know how to update the photos in database.

Here is my code, I have update function where I don't know exactly how to make the update .

```
My cars table:

    Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('model');
            $table->integer('seats');
            $table->string('fuel');
            $table->integer('year');
            $table->string('color');
            $table->string('gearbox');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->string('coinType');
            $table->timestamps();
        });


My images table

    Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('car_id');
            $table->string('file_name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });


My Car model:

    class Car extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'model',
        'seats',
        'fuel',
        'year',
        'color',
        'gearbox',
        'price',
        'coinType',
    ];

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
    }
    use HasFactory;
}

My Image model:

    class Image extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'car_id',
        'file_name'
    ];
    
    public function car()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Car::class);
    }
    use HasFactory;
}


My edit.blade:

    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 offset-sm-2">
        <h2 class="display-3">Edit a car</h2>
        <div>
            @if ($errors->any())
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div><br />
            @endif
            <form method="post" action="{{ url('cars/'. $res->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                @method('PUT')
                <div class="form-group">
                    <legend>
                        <label for="model" class="col-form-label">Model :</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="model" name="model" value="{{ $res->model }}">
                    </legend>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group ">
                    <legend>
                        <label for="seats" class="col-form-label">Seats :</label>
                    </legend>
                    <select name="seats" id="seats" value="{{ $res->seats }}">
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="4" selected="selected">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group ">
                    <legend>
                        <label for="fuel" class="col-form-label">Fuel :</label>
                    </legend>
                    <select name="fuel" id="fuel" value="{{ $res->fuel }}">
                        <option value="benzine+gpl">benzine+gpl</option>
                        <option value="gpl" selected="selected">diesel</option>
                        <option value="diesel">gpl</option>
                        <option value="diesel+gpl">diesel+gpl</option>
                        <option value="benzine">benzine</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group ">
                    <legend>
                        <label for="year" class="col-form-label">Year :</label>
                    </legend>
                    <input type="text" name="year" id="year" value="{{ $res->year }}">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <legend>
                        <label for="color" class="col-form-label">Color :</label>
                    </legend>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="color" name="color" value="{{ $res->color }}">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group ">
                    <legend>
                        <label for="gearbox" class="col-form-label">Gearbox :</label>
                    </legend>
                    <select name="gearbox" id="gearbox" value="{{ $res->gearbox }}">
                        <option value="manual">manual</option>
                        <option value="automatic" selected="selected">automatic</option>
                        <option value="semiautomatic">semiautomatic</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group ">
                    <legend>
                        <label for="price" class="col-form-label">Price :</label>
                    </legend>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" value="{{ $res->price }}">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group ">
                    <legend>
                        <label for="coinType" class="col-form-label">CoinType :</label>
                    </legend>
                    <select name="coinType" id="coinType" value="{{ $res->coinType }}">
                        <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
                        <option value="LEI" selected="selected">LEI</option>
                        <option value="USD">USD</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group ">
                    <legend>
                        <label for="image" class="col-form-label">Upload images :</label>
                    </legend>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="images[]" multiple />
                </div>


                <hr style="height:2px;border-width:0;color:gray;background-color:gray">

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 ">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add car</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('cars.index') }}"> Back</a>
                </div>
        </div>
        </form>

        @endsection
```

My Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'model' => 'required',
        'year' => 'required',
        'color' => 'required',
        'price'=> 'required',
        'file_name.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ]);

    $destionationPath = public_path('/images');
    $images = [];

    $car = new Car();
    $car->model = $request->model;
    $car->seats = $request->seats;
    $car->fuel = $request->fuel;
    $car->year = $request->year;
    $car->color = $request->color;
    $car->gearbox = $request->gearbox;
    $car->price = $request->price;
    $car->coinType = $request->coinType;
  

    $car->save();

    
    if ($files = $request->file('images')) {
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move($destionationPath, $fileName);
            $images[] = $fileName;
        }
    }

    foreach ($images as $imag) {
        $image = new Image();
        $image->car_id = $car->id;
        $image->file_name = $imag;
        $image->save();
    }


    return redirect()->route('cars.index')->with('success', 'Car saved !');
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'model' => 'required',
        'year' => 'required',
        'color' => 'required',
        'price'=> 'required',
        'file_name.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ]);

    $destionationPath = public_path('/images');
    $images = [];

    $car = Car::find($id);
    $car->model = $request->model;
    $car->seats = $request->seats;
    $car->fuel = $request->fuel;
    $car->year = $request->year;
    $car->color = $request->color;
    $car->gearbox = $request->gearbox;
    $car->price = $request->price;
    $car->coinType = $request->coinType;
  

    $car->update();

    
    if ($files = $request->file('images')) {
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move($destionationPath, $fileName);
            $images[] = $fileName;
        }
    }

    foreach ($images as $imag) {
        //here I don't know what to do
    }


    return redirect()->route('cars.index')->with('success', 'Car updated !');
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your blade file, you don't really show the original images, so the user can't update the images, he can insert new images and the old ones should be deleted, right?

If you want to update the image, you have to show the original images on the blade file with it's ID, so in the backend you can find the image based on the ID

But this should work for you now:

you can just check if the user uploaded any file

```
if ($files = $request->files('images')) {
...
```

delete all the old images

```
$car->images->each(function($image) {
    // You probabily should be using Storage facade for this
    // this should be the full path, I didn't test it, but if you need add extra methods so it returns the full path to the file
    if (file_exists($destionationPath . '/' . $image->file_name) {
        unset($destionationPath . '/' . $image->file_name);
    }

    $image->delete();
});
```

And then recreate the images like you do on store

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->move($destionationPath, $fileName);
    $images[] = $fileName;
}

foreach ($images as $imag) {
    $image = new Image();
    $image->car_id = $car->id;
    $image->file_name = $imag;
    $image->save();
}
```

Comment: One extra thing, try to implement transactions (`DB::transaction`) so if something fail on the middle of the code, you don't lose anything on database (you can't be sure about the files, to be sure you can store the paths and try to delete the files at the end of the code)